# Pass 3 columns into a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm sure a post about this problem already exists but i can't find it.
I want to create a dict following this pattern :

```
df : 
City    Lat   Lon
Paris   lat1  lon1
London  lat2  lon2
```

into this dict :

`my_dict = {Paris : {Lat : lat1, Lon : lon1}, London : {Lat : lat2, Lon : lon2}}`

is there an option like in `df.to_dict('option')` that i miss ?

Thanks !

Comment: Use `df.set_index('City').to_dict('i')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.set_index('City', inplace=True)
d = df.to_dict(orient='index')
print(d)

{'Paris': {'Lat': 'lat1', 'Lon': 'lon1'}, 'London': {'Lat': 'lat2', 'Lon': 'lon2'}}
```